# How to create a SQL view with variable where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, view

I have a table with 37 columns. The table is populated from daily csv files. I need to create a view that filters only the previous month data set. The posting date column is a string variable in the form 20131219.  I have a function that uses date functions to determine the current month, then returns a string with the year and month prior.  This query returns the data set I need, but I can't figure out how to create a view that allows the variables and function call. **the paramater '2013' doesn't do anything. I couldn't get the function to work without one, so added something.

```
declare @newstring varchar(6)
set @newstring = [dbo].[GetPrevYearMonth]('2013')
select * from dbo.SAE_EDATA_LV
where [GTR-POSTING-DATE] like @newstring+'%'
```

I know I could create a function with a table return type, but that's very tedious for the number of columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I added the SQL Server tag because this appears to be SQL Server syntax.

Comment: Do you always want to return the previous month's data, or do you want to be able to return any date range of data?

Answer (score 2):

Change your View to an inline Table-Valued Function (iTVF).  An iTVF is really just a parametized View anyway.

You use it the exactly the same, except that you have to also specify parameters.

Alternatively, you can create an iTVF wrapper for your View:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSAE_EDATA_LV(@newstring varchar(6))
RETURNS TABLE As
    select * 
    from dbo.SAE_EDATA_LV
    where [GTR-POSTING-DATE] like @newstring+'%'
```

---

You should also know that long column lists can just be dragged from a Table/View/Table-Valued function's icon/column folder on the SSMS explorer pane and dropped into a SQL session pane.